# Is there a way to take Facebook's location update and mirror it on another website?

Tags: html, css, facebook, checkin

is it possible to mirror when I update my location (or "check in") on Facebook on to a separate website?

I'm trying to find out if it is possible so that if someone checks in onto their business Facebook page then that "check in" or location update is reflected on another website so that people that don't actually use Facebook can see they are there.

If this isn't possible then no worries - just trying to see if there is a reasonably simple process to achieve this before getting into the nitty gritty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible 
Go to facebook developer.Then  Tools › Graph API Explorer
When getting the access token try to check the publish checkins. You can play with it to see what data u get actually.
You can call that using jquery ajax.